# Keep one row of dataframe under a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

Quick question --

I've got a data frame with some duplicates and I'd like to remove them **only** when `type == 'c1'`. So for instance, I just want to keep **one** row of where `type == 'c1'` for each `id`, there a way to do that with dplyr? I was about to use a `case_when` but went in circles.

```
sample_df <- data.frame(id = c(14129, 14129, 14129, 29102, 29102, 2191, 2191, 2191, 2191, 2192, 2192, 1912, 1912, 1912)
                        , date = c("2018-06-15 00:15:42","2018-10-08 12:44:44",
                                   "2018-07-09 18:14:58", "2018-06-15 00:15:40",
                                   "2018-06-15 00:19:42", "2018-10-15 08:17:47",
                                   "2018-09-29 10:16:34", "2018-07-09 18:28:25",
                                   "2018-07-09 18:28:25", "2018-07-09 18:20:32",
                                   "2018-08-30 13:06:45", "2018-10-08 11:32:55",
                                   "2018-10-05 11:32:55", "2018-10-08 09:09:56")
                        , color = c("blue", "blue", "green", "red", "red", "red", "green", "blue", "green", "purple", "blue", "blue", "red", "red")
                        , day = rep("c1", times = 14)
                        , happy = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1))

sample_df$date <- as.POSIXct(sample_df$date)

sample_df_2 <- sample_df %>% 
  gather(key, type, color:day) %>%
  mutate(happy = case_when(key == "color" ~ 0, TRUE ~ as.numeric(happy))) %>%
  select(-key) %>%
  arrange(id)

> sample_df_2
      id                date happy   type
1   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0   blue
2   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0    red
3   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     0    red
4   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0     c1
5   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0     c1
6   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     1     c1
7   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     0    red
8   2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0  green
9   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0   blue
10  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0  green
11  2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     1     c1
12  2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0     c1
13  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     1     c1
14  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0     c1
15  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0 purple
16  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     0   blue
17  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0     c1
18  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     1     c1
19 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     0   blue
20 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0   blue
21 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0  green
22 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     1     c1
23 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0     c1
24 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0     c1
25 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0    red
26 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     0    red
27 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0     c1
28 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     1     c1
```

Desired output --

```
     id                date happy   type
1   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0   blue
2   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0    red
3   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     0    red
4   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0     c1
7   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     0    red
8   2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0  green
9   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0   blue
10  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0  green
11  2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     1     c1
15  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0 purple
16  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     0   blue
17  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0     c1
19 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     0   blue
20 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0   blue
21 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0  green
22 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     1     c1
25 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0    red
26 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     0    red
27 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0     c1
```

Comment: `anyDuplicated(sample_df)` and `anyDuplicated(sample_df_2)` both indicate there are no duplicates in your data. Do you mean to ignore `date` and `happy` in your "duplicates" claim?

Comment: You don't mention the difference between `sample_df` and `sample_df_2` in your question... next time maybe just `dput(sample_df_2)` to keep things short and to-the-point.

Answer (score 4):

Base R

```
sample_df_2[ !duplicated(sample_df_2[c("id","type")]) | sample_df_2$type != "c1", ]
#       id                date happy   type
# 1   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0   blue
# 2   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0    red
# 3   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     0    red
# 4   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0     c1
# 7   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     0    red
# 8   2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0  green
# 9   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0   blue
# 10  2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0  green
# 11  2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     1     c1
# 15  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0 purple
# 16  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     0   blue
# 17  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0     c1
# 19 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     0   blue
# 20 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0   blue
# 21 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0  green
# 22 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     1     c1
# 25 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0    red
# 26 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     0    red
# 27 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0     c1
```

Tidyverse:

```
library(dplyr)
sample_df_2 %>%
  filter(!duplicated(cbind(id,type)) | type != "c1")
#       id                date happy   type
# 1   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0   blue
# 2   1912 2018-10-05 11:32:55     0    red
# 3   1912 2018-10-08 09:09:56     0    red
# 4   1912 2018-10-08 11:32:55     0     c1
# 5   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     0    red
# 6   2191 2018-09-29 10:16:34     0  green
# 7   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0   blue
# 8   2191 2018-07-09 18:28:25     0  green
# 9   2191 2018-10-15 08:17:47     1     c1
# 10  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0 purple
# 11  2192 2018-08-30 13:06:45     0   blue
# 12  2192 2018-07-09 18:20:32     0     c1
# 13 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     0   blue
# 14 14129 2018-10-08 12:44:44     0   blue
# 15 14129 2018-07-09 18:14:58     0  green
# 16 14129 2018-06-15 00:15:42     1     c1
# 17 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0    red
# 18 29102 2018-06-15 00:19:42     0    red
# 19 29102 2018-06-15 00:15:40     0     c1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`:

```
sample_df_2 %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(!duplicated(type) | type!="c1")
```